# Globally replacing text on a page, breaks/garbles it

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, userscripts

I'm trying to modify this simple userscript on Internet Explorer for my own variables to modify, it seems simple enough but when I replace the variable with my own to search and replace, websites turn up complete botched unless I refresh.

```
(function(){

    var arrGoogleInstances = document.body.innerHTML.match(/google/ig);

    if (arrGoogleInstances != null)
    {
        if (arrGoogleInstances.length > 0)
        {
            document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/google/ig,'guuuuuuuugle');
            document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/Google /ig,'Guuuuuuugle');   
        }   
    }

})();
```

For example, I tried to replace the `google` regex term with numbers.  But then, the script yet doesn't seem to work and seems to mess up my websites.

Can anyone tell me why that is?

Comment: Can you explain what "mess up" and "botch" mean? You might be replacing `google` inside of the URLs of CDN-hosted libraries.

Comment: Sure, it seems pages become complete into meaningless text versions with lots of what seems to be code. and I can even make out the very code in question albeit without spacing as well, which is very strange.

Comment: This particular code actually runs fine, it's when I try to replace it with other variables is when it fails to run. For example, I tried to replace google with a specific number and tried to replace guuuugle with a different number, and that's where the error comes in.

Comment: More specifically, when I try to replace smaller and more common variables, say the letter G, that's where I get trouble as well. Longer and less common variables seem to work fine.

Comment: `innerHTML` gives you the HTML. If you happen to replace some tag or attribute with an invalid one, the page will break.

Comment: Ah I see, do you have any idea what I can replace innerHTML with instead to just get displayed text to change? Once again I would like to point out the fact that I'm using IE.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://github.com/padolsey/findAndReplaceDOMText

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `innerHTML`! (Pretty much, ever)
What is happening is that parts of the HTML structure itself are being trashed, depending on the values you send to `.replace()`. But also, all of the javascript that makes the page work is getting destroyed or orphaned.

The correct approach is to recurse through the page's text nodes, with DOM techniques.

The code is like this, you can [**see it in action at jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LYLCr/):

```
replaceTextValues (document.body, /Google/ig, "Guuuuuuugle");


//-- Internet explorer doesn't define DOM2 constants!
if (typeof Node != "undefined") {
    TEXT_NODE       = Node.TEXT_NODE;
    ELEMENT_NODE    = Node.ELEMENT_NODE;
}
else {
    TEXT_NODE       = 3;
    ELEMENT_NODE    = 1;
}

function replaceTextValues (node, regex, replaceWith) {
    if (node.nodeType === TEXT_NODE) {
        node.nodeValue  = node.nodeValue.replace (regex, replaceWith);
    }
    else if (node.nodeType === ELEMENT_NODE) {
        for (var K = 0, numNodes = node.childNodes.length;  K < numNodes;  ++K) {
            replaceTextValues (node.childNodes[K], regex, replaceWith);
        }
    }
}
```